# Scanner variable doesn't work outside the try-catch block

Tags: java, try-catch

I tried to declare `s.next()` after the try-catch block but it wouldn't work! The `s` would only have the drop down if it is inside the try block.

I don't want to lump Parsing inputs, take appropriate actions all into the try block, because they wouldn't throw the FNFE and IOE. What can I do here?

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
      {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //Open file; file name specified in args (command line)
        try{
            FileReader freader = new FileReader(args[0]);
            Scanner s = new Scanner(freader);

        }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            System.err.println("Error: File not found. Exiting program...");
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }catch(IOException e){
            System.err.println ("Error: IO exception. Exiting...");
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        // if i try to declare s.next() here it would not work
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean you want to *use* s.next() and that it won't work.

to do that, declare s as a variable outside the try/catch block, set it to null there.  Then assign it where you assign it now, but without the declaration.  If my assumption is correct, your problem is that s is no longer an active variable outside the try/catch, because it is declared within that block.

```
FileReader freader = null;
Scanner    s       = null;
try { freader = new FileReader(args[0]); // risk null pointer exception here
      s = new Scanner(freader);
    }
catch { // etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

because `s` variable which is an instance of `Scanner` class is limited to `try` block only. if you want `s` to be accessible *outside* the `try-catch` block, declare it outside the try catch.

```
 Scanner s = null;
 try{
        FileReader freader = new FileReader(args[0]);
         s = new Scanner(freader);

    }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        System.err.println("Error: File not found. Exiting program...");
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-1);
    }catch(IOException e){
        System.err.println ("Error: IO exception. Exiting...");
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-1);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java, variables are scoped by the block they are declared in. Since your Scanner is constructed inside the `try` block, it is not visible outside of it.

Is there any reason you want to do your actual scanning operations outside this block? In Java 7, a common idiom is the *try-with-resources* pattern:

```
try (Scanner s = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(file)) {
  //Do stuff...
}
```

Which will automatically close out the Scanner resource. As it is, you could potentially leak it, since there's no `finally` block in your code sample.